# Multiple length statements

Tags: mysql

I have a problem that might be kind of basic to most of you.

I run a MySQL database and I want to write a query that involves more than one length definition.

The table has the columns `nationality` and `ID`. I want to write a query where the results return only the rows where nationality = '1' with ID length = '8' and nationality = not '1' with ID length = '4'.

Hope you get the point!

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is meaningless without a schema of the table(s) concerned.

Comment: How come it is meaningless when the user is just asking for the query formation. He wants to know how to combine rows based on different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t (id varchar(8), nationality int);
insert into t values
('aaaa',1),('defghijk',1),('bbbb',2),('nopqrstu',2);

select t.*
from    t 
where (length(id) = 8 and nationality = 1) or (length(id) = 4 and nationality <> 1);
```

note the use of brackets.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE nationality = 1
AND LEN(ID) = '4'
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE nationality <> 1
AND LEN(ID) = '8'
```

You can try above query.

Comment: That's harsh when people downvote without giving proper reason for it. It improves the learning.